# cannot post /post nodejs

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, pug

the code in my app.coffee it uses coffee script i have put body parser and method ovveride

```
           express = require("express")
          everyauth = require("everyauth")
             should = require("should")
        fs = require("fs")

      everyauth.debug = true
        usersByLogin = krishna:
          login: "krishna"
          email: "krishna@blogab.com"
             password: "krishna"

          everyauth.password.loginWith("login").getLoginPath("/login").postLoginPath("        
       /login").loginView("bcore/login.jade").loginLocals((req, res, done) ->
      setTimeout (->
       done null,
           title: "blogab - login"
          ), 200
         ).authenticate((login, password) ->
      errors = []
        errors.push "Missing login"  unless login
       errors.push "Missing password"  unless password
       return errors  if errors.length
         user = usersByLogin[login]
        return [ "Login failed" ]  unless user
        return [ "Login failed" ]  if user.password isnt password
      user
       ).getRegisterPath("/register").postRegisterPath("    

         /register").registerView("bcore                 

         /register.jade").registerLocals((req, res, done) ->
      setTimeout (->
         done null,
            title: " Register"
          ), 200
           ).extractExtraRegistrationParams((req) ->
        email: req.body.email
       ).validateRegistration((newUserAttrs, errors) ->
        login = newUserAttrs.login
        errors.push "Login already taken"  if usersByLogin[login]
        errors
         ).registerUser((newUserAttrs) ->
            login = newUserAttrs[@loginKey()]
             usersByLogin[login] = newUserAttrs
           ).loginSuccessRedirect("/admin").registerSuccessRedirect "/admin"
                    app =  express.createServer

          (express.bodyParser(),express.methodOverride(),     
             express.static(__dirname + "/public"),


                 express.session(secret: "htuayreve"),  everyauth.middleware())

              express.cookieParser(), 
               app.configure ->
             app.set "view engine", "jade"

            app.get "/", (req, res) ->
         res.render "templates/default/index",
          title: "blogab"
          users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)

         app.get "/admin", (req, res) ->
         res.render "bcore/admin",
         title: "Blogab-admin"
          users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)

           app.get "/login", (req, res) ->
            res.render "bcore/login",
             title: "login"
             users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)

               app.get "/post", (req, res) ->
                   res.render "bcore/viewpost",
                    title: "login"
                    users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)

            app.get "/admin/post/new", (req, res) ->
            res.render "bcore/newpost",
           title: "Blogab-newpost"
            users: JSON.stringify(usersByLogin, null, 2)

       everyauth.helpExpress app
         app.listen 1224, ->
          console.log "blogab is  running on port %d in %s mode",
            app.address().port,   app.setting
```

and in newpost.jade   it is the code for newpost

```
            !!! 5
           html(xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
           head
           title
          link(href='/css/master.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
          body
           h1
           | New post
           form#new_post.new_post(method='post', action='/posts')
             .field
              label(for='post_title') Title
               br
                 input#post_title(type='text', name='title', size='30')
           .field
              label(for='post_content') Content
            br
               textarea#post_content(name='content', cols='40', rows='20')
          .actions
              input#post_submit(type='submit', value='Create Post')
            p
               br
                 a(href='/posts') Back
```

when i click post it in newpost.jade it says cannot post /post and i am creating nodejs based cms i haved  used express body parser  and method ovveride

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to define the POST /posts route:

```
app.get '/posts', (req, res, next) ->
```

**Edited** to add an example, your code was really hard to read. I wrote this:

```
express = require 'express'
app = express.createServer()

app.configure ->
  app.use express.methodOverride()
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use app.router

app.post '/posts', (req, res) -> res.send req.body

app.listen 3000
```

`$ curl localhost:3000/posts -X POST -d "param1=value1&param2=value2"`

`{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}%`

Comment: still giving me Cannot POST /post

Comment: thanks it now shows post title and contents again when i refresh /post page it says post-title not defined

Comment: and where is the post contents being defined? only at the POST /posts action? (I have no clue without code..)

you should load the post again when doing GET /post

Comment: **.page-header
  h1= title
.content!=content** in this post.jade

Comment: how can we store post and retrieve it back please help

Comment: look at this example to see more or less how it should be: (I'm not sure how update the example is.. but anyway, it serves as a guide)

[Express mvc example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc)

for storage.. you need to decide what are you going to use for that.. relational database such as postgres, mysql, or something like mongodb.. that are many options

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post data to express you must define your route with the POST verb:

```
app.post '/posts', (req, res) ->
```

Also, I am not sure if you mean to define your route as '/post' or '/posts' so double check the client and server code matches.

Answer (score 0):

**app.get** will not work to post data, try using **app.post** always to post data.
it worked for me :)